# Creating associations in EDM model on unique keys

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, unique-constraint

I'm developing a new application which is based on a legacy database. The old legacy database does not use reference integrity and first we try to not change the existing schema. I still want to be be able to use navigation properties in my EF generated POCO classes.

However, the old data model has one big issue regarding child-parent relationships: the column in the child table is referencing the parent table via the uniqe key of the parent, not via the primary key of the parent table. Is it still possible to generate such associations?

I tried to mark the unique key in the parent table as "entity key" but then I still need to provide a mapping for the parent table's primary key which I am not able to because there is no mapping for it available, this primary is just a dummy "counter". If I do not provide a mapping for the primary key, I get 
"Error 111: Properties referred by the Principal Role XXX must be exactly identical to the key of the EntityType YYY referred to by the Principal Role in the relationship constraint for Relationship ZZZ. Make sure all the key properties are specified in the Principal Role"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No EF does not support unique keys at all. It is [hopefully planned feature](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unique-key-constraints-in-entity-framework/) of the next major release.

Comment: Here is my workaround: I created a new column in the child table containing a reference to the primary key from the parent table. Now I have a duplicity in the child table - a reference to the uniqe key from the parent table and a reference to the primary key from the parent table. It is not nice, I know, but I must live with that, because it was probably the only solution except generating my domain objects by my own. I hope that the new EF with support for Unique Keys will be available soon so that I can remove this duplicity. Thanks again, Ladislav.